# how to prevent user from entering prohibited username in html form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

So I have a social network with a sign up form. Is there any way I can **prevent** a user from entering a username that is a folder or file on my server?

For example www.example.com/username   **I don't want users to choose usernames that are files or folders on my server**

Comment: Check for an existing file or directory using PHP?

Comment: makes no senes that a folder or file name, as a username, would be an issue, unless you are doing some really silly things. if I register as **php.ini**, will that crash your site ? :-)

Comment: I think you're approaching this in the wrong way.  Consider how will this work for you when a user named 'foo' registers with your site, and then sometime in the future you create a file or directory named 'foo' on your site.

Comment: If this is really an issue then why not add one more route? `www.example.com/user/username`

Comment: why not check your directory, for filenames that is equal to the users input? make sense? or add somthing to your folder names thats unique, BUT WHY THE NEED?. .

Answer (score 3):

Just use `file_exists` (and make sure the directory it points to is correct). For example:

```
if(file_exists($escaped_username)) {
    echo "Can't use that username.";
}
```

Though if you find yourself needing to make this check, perhaps you need to rethink the design a little.